# Oracle SQL - Get records with latest date on non-unique data

Tags: sql, oracle

Following is the example of records in the table -

```
ITEM_NAME   STORAGE_CODE   STOCK   DATE
ABC         2233           170     27/09/2017
ABC         2233           270     15/09/2017
DEF         2233           120     23/09/2017
DEF         2233           110     11/09/2017
GHI         2233           50      15/09/2017
```

Expected result:

```
ITEM_NAME   STORAGE_CODE   STOCK   DATE
ABC         2233           170     27/09/2017
DEF         2233           120     23/09/2017
GHI         2233           50      15/09/2017
```

I've tried using the below query:

```
Select ITEM_NAME, STORAGE_CODE, STOCK, MAX(DATE) 
FROM ITEM_TABLE 
WHERE ITEM_NAME IN ('ABC','DEF','GHI' .........) 
GROUP BY ITEM_NAME, STORAGE_CODE, STOCK
```

This didn't work as the stock value is not unique.

Please note: I'm using `ITEM_NAME IN ()`, because I need the output for some specific items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `select top` and `order by` to your query if you just want to get the `max` date, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 1
       ITEM_NAME,
       STORAGE_CODE,
       STOCK,
       MAX(DATE)
FROM ITEM_TABLE
WHERE ITEM_NAME IN('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
GROUP BY ITEM_NAME,
         STORAGE_CODE,
         STOCK
ORDER BY DATE DESC
```

EDIT: Using row_num

```
SELECT T.ITEM_NAME,
       T.STORAGE_CODE,
       T.STOCK,
       T.DATE
FROM
(
    SELECT ITEM_NAME,
           STORAGE_CODE,
           STOCK,
           DATE,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ITEM_NAME,
                                          STORAGE_CODE ORDER BY DATE DESC) AS part
    FROM ITEM_TABLE
    WHERE ITEM_NAME IN('ABC', 'DEF', 'GHI')
) T
WHERE part = 1;
```

Comment: As per my understanding, TOP doesn't work in Oracle.

Comment: ahhh, didn't catch the Oracle tag. You can use `where rownum = 1` or look at using a `rank ()` function

Comment: Sorry, but even if I use 'rownum' instead of 'TOP', that would give me just 1 record (Ex: only ABC record) I need output with records for all the items (ABC, DEF, GHI). Please correct if I'm wrong.

Comment: @RajatSolanki I've added in another way to do it using the `ROW_NUMBER` function

Comment: thank you so much. Could you please briefly explain how this works ? I'm not very familiar with OVER(PARTITION BY)

Comment: basically it partitions the table on the column you chose in the partition by part then orders it by another column, so it will give a row number 1 to the first column in the partition and 2 to the next and so on. then you just add a where clause to get the first row. the Oracle docs are here: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm

Answer (score 0):

I think a query like this should work:

```
select 
    *
from (
    select *,
        row_number() over (partition by ITEM_NAME, STORAGE_CODE order by DATE desc) as seq
    from ITEM_TABLE
    where ITEM_NAME in ('ABC','DEF','GHI' .........)
) t
where seq = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Oracle `row_number() over(partition by)` like following

```
select ITEM_NAME
     , STORAGE_CODE
     , STOCK
     , DATE
from 
(
    select ITEM_NAME
        , STORAGE_CODE
        , STOCK
        , DATE
        , row_number() over(partition by ITEM_NAME order by DATE desc) as rn
    from ITEM_TABLE
) s
where rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to get the `max` value from `DATE1` column in inner query and corresponding `stock` value in outer query using `join` as below.

```
SELECT t.*
    ,t1.STOCK
FROM (
    SELECT ITEM_NAME
        ,STORAGE_CODE
        ,MAX(DATE1) AS DATE1
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY ITEM_NAME
        ,STORAGE_CODE
    ORDER BY ITEM_NAME
    ) t
INNER JOIN table1 t1 ON t.ITEM_NAME = t1.ITEM_NAME
    AND t.STORAGE_CODE = t1.STORAGE_CODE
    AND t.DATE1 = t1.DATE1
```

**Result:**

```
ITEM_NAME   STORAGE_CODE         DATE1           STOCK
------------------------------------------------------
ABC            2233       27.09.2017 00:00:00     170
DEF            2233       23.09.2017 00:00:00     120
GHI            2233       15.09.2017 00:00:00     50
```

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/SCR56390)**